# Laravel - Localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

We had one app developed almost a year ago and here I'm facing a problem.
After signing in the chrome says: `The localhost page isn’t working, localhost redirected you too many times.`.
And the problem lies in this piece of code at controller that while I remove it, it works fine. I couldn't figure out what is wrong with this.

```
if(Auth::check()){
        $usertype=usertype::where('uid','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
        if(isset($usertype)){
        if($usertype->type==1){
            $shopcatagory=shopcatagory::where('sid','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
            $shopsubcatagory=shopsubcatagory::where('sid','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
            $shopphone=shopphone::where('sid','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
            $shopaddress=shopaddress::where('sid','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
            $shopplace=shopplace::where('sid','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
            if(!isset($shopaddress) || !isset($shopcatagory) || !isset($shopsubcatagory) || !isset($shopphone) || !isset($shopplace)){
                return Redirect::action('HomeController@accountinfo',Auth::user()->id);
            }
        }

        else if($usertype->type==3){
            $shopphone=shopphone::where('sid','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
            $shopaddress=shopaddress::where('sid','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
            $shopplace=shopplace::where('sid','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
            if(!isset($shopaddress) || !isset($shopphone) || !isset($shopplace)){
                return Redirect::action('HomeController@accountinfo',Auth::user()->id);
            }
        }

        else if($usertype->type == 2){
            $userinterests=userinterests::where('uid','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
            if(!isset($userinterests)){
                return Redirect::action('HomeController@interests');
            }
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Apart from code being so glued together it's difficult to read, it's obvious there's an infinite loop going on. Simply read through that cabbage and determine which parts can fail and whether you handled that failure or not (from a glimpse on this salad you produced, your code can fail at so many places it's not worth writing an answer to highlight each one).

Comment: While posting this I thought the same thing, as it was our first experience with Laravel and now I can't change all of them to just make it better. It is obvious that it is a spaghetti code and I'm feeling bad while I saw this.

Comment: @jszobody post it as an answer so I can check it as correct answer. Yes these checks were running there and removing them solved the problem.

Comment: @AkmalArzhang done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this big `Auth::check` block, there are two different routes that you are potentially redirecting to: `accountinfo` and `interests`.

So if you are getting stuck in an infinite loop, then it sounds like this very code is running on one (or both) of those very routes!

Track that down, make sure that neither of those two routes include this `Auth::check` code with the redirects.